# iphone application for tabbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

i want to reload the third tab bar when click on OK button.
And the OK button is in second tab bar.
so how can i go to direct in the third tab bar from second tab bar. with reload the webview.
please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OK button click

```
yourTabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;//or whatever index you want..
```

or use

```
[yourTabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

And to reload the view in 3rd tab, Put your reload code in viewWillAppear() function of your viewController of 3rd tab..